# How to extract nested fields from MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

So my problem is that I have a database structure (designed by someone else and I have to work on it now) as follows:

```
DBS:
Database 1
Database 2
Database 3
    Collection 1
    Collection 2
            field_1
                    field_1_1
                            field_1_1_1
                    field_1_2
            field_2
            field_3
    Collection 3
    Collection 4
Database 4
```

Now I want to extract the field **field_1_1_1** any idea how I can query that?

So far I have tried applying find_one on Database 3.Collection 2.filed_1.field_1_1.field_1_1_1 but obviously it did not work.

So here goes the actual content as requested. This is what 1 item in the collection "tempStorage" under the database "workApp" looks like.

```
        {"_id":{"tag":"i4x","org":"Temp","course":"CXV_08","category":"about","name":"overview","revision":null},
        "definition":
            {"data":
                {"data":
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
uis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
onsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
illum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
roident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Uploaded the actual fields.

What does work is if I export the entire collection and then parse through it but the data is already .4 GB and I do not think that that can be the only option and that there must exist something better.

Anyone with good experience in MongoDB who can help me out?

Comment: Instead of virtually showing your DB please post some field so that I can check with query and obtained results.

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari I updated an actual field from the content. The query I am applying right now in R is mongo.find.one(m,ns) where m is the mongodb connection string and ns ="workApp.tempStorage". Sorry for the late response by the way.

Comment: Thanks for actual collection, I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = db.tempStorage.find()
data[0].definition.data.data
```

Here, `db.tempStorage.find()` will give you all the results in an Array variable `data`, which you can iterate by passing an index value and using dot notation to reach out deep into the document as I have done in `data[0].definition.data.data`.

If you have only 1 document within collection than `findOne()` can also be used.

```
var data = db.tempStorage.findOne()
data.definition.data.data
```

HTH!

Thanks.